# Shortcut to anchor a cell in Google Sheets + Chrome + Mac + 2020

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Whats the shortcut to use from this A1:A229 to make it $A$1:$A$229.
F4 and Cmd F4 do not work in Google Sheets + Chrome + Mac + 2020.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**`Fn`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`F4`**</kbd>

### ____________________________________________________

[image]

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&visit_id=637202590745115819-3984292513&rd=1